# How to show more annoations on mkmapview when zooming in and show less on zoom out?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a map with multiple annotations like 40, So initially I want to show only 6 annotations on the map with default zooming level which would cover all annotations. This 6 annotations would be at index 0, 7, 15, 23, 31, 39 accordingly. Once I start zooming I want to show more annotations based on the dynamic zoom level like 0, 4, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39 and so on.

Comment: it default behaviour in ios 11

Comment: Its not default behaviour as I added all the annotations and each is having image and right now all are getting shown with overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0):

Set `annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = nil`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: annotation)
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = nil
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: This wont be of my case. I have annotations to draw a route and all are showing so something to do with regionDidChangeAnimated - this method to dynamically show/hide annotations based on zoom level.